# Api Call in Next.js Project On vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have an API that works on localhost without authentication, but in production on Vercel, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "bad auth: authentication failed"
}
```

However, I don't have any authentication set up for this API. Does anyone know why I'm experiencing this error? Does Vercel have any specific configuration requirements in this regard?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB? Can you share the API endpoint code?

Comment: Yes, im usfing mongoDb:

My mongo Connection:

import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const uri = `mongodb+srv://jmyname:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.mues8vo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

export default client;

Comment: Please share your code for the API endpoint. You can edit the post and add the snippet.

Comment: my .env on vercel was wrong data, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

My .env file on Vercel was set to an outdated database password. I had recently updated the password on MongoDB, but forgot to change it on Vercel, causing errors and functionality issues.